# iOS8: Auto-layout and Gradient

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, gradient

**Setup:**

I have a `View Controller` that consists of a `View` and a `Container View`.

[image]

The `View` (Orange) is `pinned` to `top` 0, `left` 0, and `right` 0.

The `Container View` (Gray) is `pinned` to `bottom` 0, `left` 0, and `right` 0.

The `View`'s `Bottom Space to: Container View` = 0

The `View`'s `Proportional Height to Container` View = 1

**Desired Results:**
I would like to add gradient to the background of the `View` (Orange)

**Tried:**

I'm using Auto-layout with class sizes to get different behavior on different screen.

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backgroundColor = CAGradientLayer().graphViewBackgroundColor()
        backgroundColor.frame = self.graphView.frame

        self.graphView.layer.addSublayer(backgroundColor)
}
```

I have a category:

```
extension CAGradientLayer {

    func graphViewBackgroundColor() -> CAGradientLayer {

        let topColor = UIColor(red: (160/255.0), green: (160/255.0), blue: (160/255.0), alpha: 1)
        let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (52/255.0), green: (53/255.0), blue: (52/255.0), alpha: 1)

        let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
        let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
        gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations

        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see gradient did not cover the entire `View`.

**Question:**  How can I get the gradient to cover the entire `View`

**Update:**

When I place the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`  It looks weird when I rotate:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do it this inside viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubview() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews
  backgroundColor.frame = self.graphView.bounds
}
```

viewDidLayoutSubviews should be called when you rotate the device.

If it is not called, override this method and do it as,

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
  super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

  backgroundColor.frame = self.graphView.bounds
}
```

Comment: Please, see the changes

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Also, when I did clip subviews in Storyboard, that also worked.  Do you want include that as part of your answer?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne This was super-easy, clean and helpful. Other things I looked at would be educational for a Swift/iOS newbie but way more complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting your gradient code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`

When `viewDidLoad` is called the views are not laid out (ie do not have their final frames set yet), so this is why you are only seeing a partial coverage of the gradient

Comment: Saying thanks for this too since it prompted the chosen answer to be improved.