# Applying gradient colour to storyboard view with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, cagradientlayer

I have added a UIView in the storyboard and want to set its background with gradient colors.
This is my code

```
extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackground(colors: [CGColor]) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
}
```

and in the viewcontroller,

```
viewSocial.setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor.gradientBottomColor.cgColor, UIColor.gradientTopColor.cgColor])
```

But this creates double gradient layers.  [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD2Jh.png)

I have tried adding a class for GradientLayer as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39591959/15266568). But this is not allowing to set on a view from the storyboard. Gives the warning of the weak variable.

Comment: where you call setGradientBackground ?

Comment: I’d recommend creating a `UIView` whose `layerClass` is a `CAGradientLayer`. (That’s preferable to adding a `CALayer` subclass as it will respond to layout changes and rotations more gracefully.) And if you make it `@IBDesignable`, you can see this rendered in IB, too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37039106/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278350/1271826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to make a `@IBDesignable` gradient view. It's using the default top-to-bottom gradient direction:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyGradientView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var color1: UIColor = .red {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    @IBInspectable var color2: UIColor = .yellow {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // use self.layer as the gradient layer
        gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
    }
    
}
```

It has `@IBInspectable` vars for "color1" and "color2" ... changing them in the Attributes Inspector will be reflected in Storyboard.

No need for any additional code, such as your current approach with `setGradientBackground()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code of `@IBDesignable` Gradient View. You can use Top to Bottom and Left to Right from `Storyboard`.

```
private var startGradientColorAssociatedKey : UIColor = .black
private var endGradientColorAssociatedKey : UIColor = .black
private var observationGradientView: NSKeyValueObservation?

extension UIView {


@IBInspectable var startGradientColor: UIColor {
    get {
        if let color = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &startGradientColorAssociatedKey) as? UIColor {
            return color
        } else {
            return .black
        }
    } set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &startGradientColorAssociatedKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var endGradientColor: UIColor {
    get {
        if let color = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &endGradientColorAssociatedKey) as? UIColor {
            return color
        } else {
            return .black
        }
    } set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &endGradientColorAssociatedKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
}


@IBInspectable
var isTopToBottomGradient: Bool {
    get {
        return self.isTopToBottomGradient
    }
    set {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if newValue {
                self.setGradientBackground(colorTop: self.startGradientColor, colorBottom: self.endGradientColor)
            } else {
                self.setGradientBackground(colorLeft: self.startGradientColor, colorRight: self.endGradientColor)
            }
        }
    }
}


func setGradientBackground(colorLeft: UIColor, colorRight: UIColor) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorLeft.cgColor, colorRight.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    observationGradientView = self.observe(\.bounds, options: .new) { [weak gradientLayer] view, change in
        if let value =  change.newValue {
            gradientLayer?.frame = value
        }
    }
    
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
}
```

Use from `Storyboard` : If you want to set gradient from top to bottom then set `ON` `isTopToBottomGradient` key. Defalt value is `OFF`

[image]