# UIButton gradient effect issue on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My question is not regarding how to set gradient for `UIButton`, but where to set it. This is how I am setting it :

```
let btnGradient = CAGradientLayer()
btnGradient.frame = button_start_course.bounds
btnGradient.colors = [(UIColor(red: 174.0 / 255.0, green: 127.0 / 255.0, blue: 183.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef), (UIColor(red: 78.0 / 255.0, green: 57.0 / 255.0, blue: 96.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef)]
button_start_course.layer.insertSublayer(btnGradient, atIndex: 0)
```

When I call this in `viewDidLoad`, **button_start_course** gives incorrect bounds. To fix this, I called this code in `viewDidAppear`. It works fine except for, the colour originally set for **button_start_course** on `storyboard` appears first and then it changes to the gradient color.
How to fix this ?

Comment: In Autolayout, correct frame of view will be available in viewDidAppear(based on screen size).. So one approach is, hide the button initially. Set the color in viewDidAppear and unhide the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. To call it once, declare a boolean that set to true when the view did finish laying out subview.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   if !viewDidLayoutSubviews {
      viewDidLayoutSubviews = true
      // Code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Rijo was a little quick :)

Comment: @Nitish Rijo's answer is somehow right. But since viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times, your button will have a stack of gradient layers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the gradient inside `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Seems to be correct. I was looking for setting the gradient in storyboard instead. But this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

set the gradient inside the `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Behaves same as in viewDidLoad

Comment: In Autolayout, correct frame of view will be available in viewDidAppear(based on screen size).

Comment: @Nitish Have you checked this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172151/ios8-auto-layout-and-gradient) .. Not sure it may help u